# Mask collision between two sprite groups

Tags: python, class, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

My player attacks by throwing their weapon at the enemies. This is currently done by using a singular sword that gets thrown, then teleports back to the player to be thrown again. I want to change this so that I have a class called sword which I can call when the player wants to throw a weapon. However, I have no idea how to do collision between to sprite groups. Heres an example of how my collision currently works (Its easier to just show the whole enemy class)

```py
class Bat(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, bat_x, bat_y, bat_image, bat_health, bat_immune, const, dash_counter, dash, dash_time, fly_count, fly_time): #There is an indent in the actual code, but stack overflow removed it in copying and pasting
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.bat_health = bat_health
        self.bat_immune = bat_immune
        self.const = const
        self.dash_counter = dash_counter
        self.dash = dash
        self.dash_time = dash_time
        self.fly_count = fly_count
        self.fly_time = fly_time
        self.image = bat_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.rect.topleft = (bat_x, bat_y)
        self.bat_x = bat_x
        self.bat_y = bat_y

    def fly(self):
        global dash_time 
        global dash
        global const
        x = player_rect.centerx - self.rect.centerx
        y = player_rect.centery - self.rect.centery
        if x == 0:
            x = 0.1
        if y == 0:
            y = 0.1
        self.dash_counter = random.randint(0, 120)
        if self.dash_counter == 30:
            if self.dash == False:
                self.dash_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() ##def self in __init__
                self.dash = True
                self.const = 5.5
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.dash_time > 1500:
            self.dash = False
            self.const = 3
        norm = (x**2 + y**2)**0.5
        self.bat_x += self.const * x / norm
        self.bat_y += self.const * y / norm

        if self.const * y / norm > 0:
            if self.fly_count == 0:
                self.image = bat_front1
                self.fly_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                self.fly_count = 1
            if self.fly_count == 1:
                if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.fly_time > 600:
                    self.image = bat_front2
                    if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.fly_time > 1200:
                        self.fly_count = 0



        if self.const * y / norm < 0:
            if self.fly_count == 0:
                self.image = bat_back1
                self.fly_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                self.fly_count = 1
            if self.fly_count == 1:
                if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.fly_time > 600:
                    self.image = bat_back2
                    if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.fly_time > 1200:
                        self.fly_count = 0            


    def update(self): ##RELEVANT##
        global player_immune
        global player_health
        global immune_time
        global player_hitsound
        global enemy_hitsound
        global dmg_multiplier
        self.rect.topleft = (self.bat_x, self.bat_y)       
        bat_immune = False
        bat_health = 5
        offsetP2B = (int(x - self.bat_x), int(y - self.bat_y)) #Player to Bat
        resultP2B = self.mask.overlap(player_mask, offsetP2B)
        if resultP2B:
            if player_immune == False:
                if invincibility_potion_activ == False:
                    player_health -= 1 
                    player_hitsound.play()
                    immune_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    player_immune = True

        offsetS2B = (int(fx - self.bat_x), int(fy - self.bat_y)) #Sword to Bat 
        resultS2B = self.mask.overlap(sword_mask, offsetS2B)
        if resultS2B:
            if self.bat_immune == False:
                if fire == True:
                    self.bat_health -= 1 * dmg_multiplier
                    enemy_hitsound.play()
                    self.bat_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    self.bat_immune = True    
        if self.bat_health <= 0:
            self.kill()

        if self.bat_immune == True:
            if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.bat_time > 100:
                self.bat_immune = False        
        self.fly()  

    all_bats = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

This works perfectly, but I want my weapon to be like the enemies, a sprite group so I can have multiple on the screen at one time, but then how would I do the collision?? I honestly have no clue how to work around this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe pygame.sprite.[groupcollide()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) is what you are looking for?  "Find all sprites that collide between two groups."

You could also use pygame.sprite.[spritecollideany()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany) if you wanted to go through them one sword at time.